# Why would a plane fly in circles for 6-7 hours and then land?

Tags: flight-path

I've seen similar questions asked but when I look at the flight path this seems quite different:
https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/f-gjfa
[image]

I'm trying to figure out why that kind of plane would fly in circles for 6-7 hours and then land.

Comment: See also: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80395/what-is-this-plane-flying-in-overlapping-circles-pattern-doing

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The aircraft **F-GJFA** is operated by **Aero-Sotravia** and is used (among other things) for live broadcasting of TV signals during sporting events:

> [image: Schema Relay]
>
> 5 dedicated planes are available, they have been specially modified to
> accommodate live recording equipment. This fleet makes us as the
> largest European operator with more than 95% of the annual volume of
> aerial television relay.
>
> We broadcast the best of sporting events (Tour De France and other
> cycling races, many marathons including Paris, IRC and WRC car
> rallies, cross-country skiing, etc.) as well as major current events
> (presidential elections, Telethon, etc.).

<sup>([Aero-Sotravia - Television relay](https://www.aero-sotravia.com/en/solutions/television-relay/))</sup>

The flight you show was on 20 May, which coincides with the [Giro d'Italia](https://www.giroditalia.it/en/the-route/) sector from Sierre to Cassano Magnago:

> [image: Route]

<sup>(modified from [cyclingnews.com](https://www.cyclingnews.com/races/giro-d-italia-2023/map/))</sup>

Comment: Giro riders are fast, but planes are faster, hence flying a helix along the stage.  Maybe they should fit out an AN-2 as a relay aircraft (though it might not have a high enough ceiling for the lines of sight).